# WebdriverIO Window.datalayer shows Window is not defined how can i resolve this

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO to inspect the window.datalayer property values.
In my code I have

```
browser.execute('return window.datalayer');
console.log(window.datalayer)
```

It shows the error window is not defined.  How do I define, declare this variable please?
If I can see the values in window.datalayer then I can do assertions on it.

My code snippet is

```
import { expect as chaiExpect, expect } from 'chai';
import 'chai/register-should';
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('TestA', () => {
   it('browse to testsite, () => {
       browser.url('https://localhost:1080/testsite')
   })
});
   
describe('login to testsite', () => {
   it('login'), () => {
      const LoginButton = $('div[class="Header__Login"] button[data-testid="login-button"]');
      const UsernameField = $('#Username');
      const PasswordField = $('Password');
      const LoginSubmitButton = $('button[Type*=submit]');
      LoginButton.click();
      browser.execute('return window.datalayer');
      console.log(window.datalayer)
      UsernameField.setValue('user1');
      PasswordField.setValue('abc123');
      LoginSubmitButton.click();
   });
});
```

I tried to define window like below.  It does not work

```
return client.exexute(function () {
    return window;
})
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't assigned returned value to anything

`const dl = browser.execute('return window.datalayer');`
Then work with `dl` variable instead of what you trying to do.

Not sure what is `window.datalayer` in your code. Do you understand the difference between NodeJS app context and browser context?